# Tomcat 9.0.75: RewriteRule explanation and example

Tags: tomcat, mod-rewrite, tomcat9

My Apache Tomcat version is 9.0.75.

To access my application, the URL is like https://mydomain/ords/r/workspace/myapp

This URL is not user-friendly. I would like the user be able to use https://mydomain2
Internally, this URL would be interpreted as https://mydomain/ords/r/workspace/myapp

I heard about RewriteRule. I did some tests but I didn't succeed.

For instance, in my Tomcat conf folder, server.xml file, I have this :

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
```

Then I put a rewrite.config in my conf\Catalina\localhost folder.

Its content is for instance:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mycustomappdomain.extension$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://myserverdomain.extension/ords/r/myappworkspace/myappname/$1 [L,R=302]
```

I also add myserverdomain.extension to my host file as localhost. I restart Tomcat.
From the server, I test the URL typing myserverdomain.extension. However the page is not found as it's supposed to be myserverdomain.extension/ords/r/myappworkspace/myappname

Could you give me some advice?

On this URL, they rather use the context.xml file : https://www.methics.fi/tomcat9-rewritevalve-usage/
Each page, each process… I don't know which one is correct.

Thank you everyone